# Why it doesnt send an email?

Tags: java, php, android

my code is about sending an email in background. I had try this codes (from stackoverflow) but it doesn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText email;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email); 

    addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View view) { 

            new SendEmailAsyncTask().execute();
        }

        class SendEmailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean> {
            Mail m = new Mail("gmailusername@gmail.com", "password");

            public SendEmailAsyncTask() {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)    
          Log.v(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), "SendEmailAsyncTask()");
                String[] toArr = { "bla@bla.com", "lala@lala.com"};
                m.setTo(toArr);
                m.setFrom("wooo@wooo.com");
                m.setSubject("Email from Android");
                m.setBody("body.");
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                  Log.v(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), "doInBackground()");
                try {
                    m.send();
                    return true;
                } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
                    Log.e(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), "Bad account 
                         details");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    Log.e(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), m.getTo(null) + 
                "failed");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            }
            });
        }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

and this is my class

```
 public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
 private String _user; 
 private String _pass; 

 private String[] _to; 
 private String _from; 

 private String _port; 
 private String _sport; 

 private String _host; 

 private String _subject; 
 private String _body; 

 private boolean _auth; 

 private boolean _debuggable; 

 private Multipart _multipart; 


 public Mail() { 
 _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
 _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
 _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

 _user = ""; // username 
 _pass = ""; // password 
 _from = ""; // email sent from 
 _subject = ""; // email subject 
 _body = ""; // email body 

 _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
 _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

 _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

 // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the  
 multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
 MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
 mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
 mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
 mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-
 handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
 mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-
 handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
 mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-
 handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
 CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
 } 

 public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
 this(); 

 _user = user; 
 _pass = pass; 
} 

 public boolean send() throws Exception { 
 Properties props = _setProperties(); 

 if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") 
 &&    
 !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
  Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

  MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

  msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

  InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
    addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
  } 
    msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

  msg.setSubject(_subject); 
  msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

  // setup message body 
  BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
  messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
  _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

  // Put parts in message 
  msg.setContent(_multipart); 

  // send email 
  Transport.send(msg); 

  return true; 
  } else { 
  return false; 
  } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
  BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
  DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
  messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
  messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

  _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
  return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
  Properties props = new Properties(); 

  props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

  if(_debuggable) { 
  props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
  } 

  if(_auth) { 
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
  } 

  props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

  return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
 public String getBody() { 
 return _body; 
 } 

 public void setBody(String _body) { 
 this._body = _body; 
 }

  public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  this._to=toArr;
 }

  public void setFrom(String string) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  this._from=string;
 }

  public void setSubject(String string) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  this._subject=string;
  }

  public String getTo(Object object) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
  }  

 }
```

i already add the activation.jar, mail.jar and additional.jar and even the the permission in manifest   .
it really made me upset that i already use the asynctask but still not working. pls help me. i am new in android and i dont know what to do next.

Comment: Where is the php code?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem with your **SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName()**